# How do I make Django Website public on my local network?

Tags: python, django, networking, web-development-server

I am building a website for myself and family in Django and React. Every time I ask them to check my process and get their opinions they get a webpage not found error or this site can't be reached. How do I make is so that anyone on my local network can check my page when its running. This is the default in flask, I don't understand why django runs like this? (safety maybe?) I can't find any good information on how to add an allow all to the ALLOWED_HOSTS section in the settings of the main app.

I also know that you can add IP address, But I'm a noob and I don't follow how to get the ip address of all my families devices without alot of work?? Does anyone have a good solution for this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django documentation:

> When DEBUG is True and ALLOWED_HOSTS is empty, the host is validated
> against ['.localhost', '127.0.0.1', '[::1]'].

If you are in debug mode with an empty list, or in non-debug mode also with an empty list, no one in your LAN network could be accessed to your website.

In this case, because you are in a LAN, you could use:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Then run

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

You don't need to open any ports on your router if you are in LAN, but maybe you need to configure your firewall in your local machine.

Otherwise, a web server like nginx or apache is recommended.

Comment: So I would have to deploy something like apache for them to see it on the local server??

Comment: Not necessarily. You could not do it without using something like apache, but it is recommended if you are going to expose the web server to the internet or in production (DEBUG=False, otherwise the server will not work, also in Django documentation).

Comment: For now I just want friends and family to check it out. When I run python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 and then have them go to https://0.0.0.0:8000 they are still getting that error. I also disabled my firewall and theirs. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The problem there is that 0.0.0.0:8000 is your local host ip, They have to introduce your ipv4 from your machine, something like 192.168.x.x. You can check your ipv4 in windows with ipconfig in the cmd. 
Or here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/find-your-ip-address-f21a9bbc-c582-55cd-35e0-73431160a1b9

Comment: So if anyone is reading this in the future, all you need to did is ipconfig and then enter at whatever port you have set. So it would be <your ip address>:8000 or 10.0.0.21:8000

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple

1. just go to your command line and type ipconfig if its windows and ifconfig if it is linux
2. Note your ip address on your local network
3. Write that address in allowed hosts in settings.py
4. Run command python manage.py runserver :
5. Take any device connect to your local network and in its browser window type servers ip:port number
   For eg 192.168.25.1:8080

Answer (score 1):

If all are on the same network then run

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: I did, but I'm getting the same error when I login to their machines and go to https://0.0.0.0:8000 Am I doing it wrong??

Comment: Put your ip like 192.168.1.x you can get it from network interface info

Answer (score 1):

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

But this is not your real problem.  You'll most likely need to open ports in the firewall of either your local machine or your router (or both) before other machines on the network will be able to reach yours.