# How to deploy django based website running on a docker compose to my local home network?

Tags: django, docker, networking

I have the following setup:
docker-compose.yml

```yaml
# Mentioning which format of dockerfile
version: "3.9"
# services or nicknamed the container
services:
  # web service for the web
  web:
    # you should use the --build flag for every node package added
    build: .
    # Add additional commands for webpack to 'watch for changes and bundle it to production'
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .
        target: /code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - "DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=django-insecure-m#x2vcrd_2un!9b4la%^)ou&hcib&nc9fvqn0s23z%i1e5))6&"
      - "DJANGO_DEBUG=True"
    expose:
      - 8000
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    #
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    # unsure of what this environment means.
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"
      # - "POSTGRES_USER=postgres"
# Volumes set up
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

and a settings file as

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']
#127.0.0.1 is my localhost address.
```

With my host's IP as `192.168.0.214`
Can you please help me deploy the django site on my host's local network?
Do I have to set up something on my router?
Or could you direct me towards resources(understanding networking) which will help me understand the same.

Comment: As you've shown it, if your host's IP address is 192.168.0.1 then the server should be reachable on `http://192.168.0.1:8000`; that configuration looks correct (I might delete the obsolete `expose:` option and the unnecessary `command:` and `volumes:` blocks but those shouldn't be a functional difference).  What happens if you try to call it?

Comment: I have tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67877796/how-do-i-make-django-website-public-on-my-local-network) guide. But the answers don't seem to help. I have checked by trying to visit my IP:8000 from a different device. Page throws 503 error. I do not know what to configure in my firewall too.

Comment: With the above setup, I can view the website on my hosting node @ `127.0.0.1:8000` which has to be the loopback interface IP and `localhost:8000`. How can I access the website through the IP of my hosting node `192.168.0.214`.